# AngularJS: is it possible to invalidate a specific form input field from the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a text input field for address, whenever the address is entered and search button next to the input field is clicked, I geocode the address and replace the input text with the result from the geocoder. I also set a scope variable 'addressOk'.

is it possible to invalidate this specific form input field according to `$scope.addressOk` or do I have to write a directive for this address geocoding input that invalidates the form when needed ?

Comment: What do you mean by invalidate?

Comment: I mean that to mark that field as invalid so the form can't be submitted

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/8dt94/23/ Looks like, It is not possible, Please post this question on mailing-list.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js Checking this out can help too.

Comment: I found the solution myself and posted the answer

Answer (score 41):

I found the solution, add a name attribute to the `<form>` and `<input>`, and then in the controller its possible to do `$scope.formName.inputName.$setValidity(errorKey, isValid)`.

Then, its possible to display errors with something like `ng-show="formName.inputName.$error.errorkey"`

according to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form If name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

Comment: What if ```inputName```is a variable?

Comment: @lightalex justuse the object notation ;) `$scope.formName[inputName].$setValidity(...)`

Comment: After you have added a custom boolean property to yourFieldName.$error object via $setValidity, you can use AngularJS ngMessages to display the appropriate error message.