# AngularJS: How do I manually set input to $valid in controller?

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

Using the [TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin and using AngularJS built-in formController validation.

Right now I'm trying to check if the field contains text, and then set field to valid if it does. The issue with using the plugin is it creates it's own input and then a ul+li for stlying.

I have access to addItem (formname) and my capablities in the controller, I just need to set it to $valid.

Markup.

```
<form class="form-horizontal add-inventory-item" name="addItem">
     <input id="capabilities" name="capabilities" token-input data-ng-model="inventoryCapabilitiesAutoComplete" data-on-add="addCapability()" data-on-delete="removeCapability()" required>
     <div class="required" data-ng-show="addItem.capabilities.$error.required" title="Please enter capability."></div>
</form>
```

JS.

```
$scope.capabilityValidation = function (capability) {
  if (capability.name !== "") {
    addItem.capabilities.$valid = true;
    addItem.capabilities.$error.required = false;
  } else {
    addItem.capabilities.$valid = false;
    addItem.capabilities.$error.required = true;
  }
};
```

I'm running the capabilityValidation function when TokenInput has something entered and passing in the object.

**EDIT:**

Found out ng-model on my input does stuff and gets the autocomplete results, which is why I can't get ng-valid to work since it's based on the model.

```
$scope.inventoryCapabilitiesAutoComplete = {
  options: {
    tokenLimit: null
  },
  source: urlHelper.getAutoComplete('capability')
};
```

I didn't write this autocomplete implementation, is there another way to do this where I would have access to the ng-model attr and move the model function somewhere else?

Comment: Since your plugin is creating its own input, and you have write a function to do your own validation, why not just use your own $scope property for validation too:  `<div ... data-ng-show="capabilities_error" ...>`  In other words, is there a reason you want/need to use FormController?

Comment: Since all my other forms are using it I'd like to keep the control it gives. The plugin created input actually sets the value in my original input, which I then need to check against in my validation but it doesn't update the formController when there's an inputted value.

Comment: I Shortened the markup on purpose to isolate the input. I have a bunch more inputs in this same form.

Comment: Okay.  Did you try `addItem.capabilities.$valid = true` and/or setting  addItem.capabilities.$error.required to true or false as appropriate?

Comment: I tried both of those. I'll update my question to show you. The $valid and $error.required shows as undefined on my breakpoint in the controller but addItem.capabilities still has data.

Comment: Bummer it didn't work.  I'm out of ideas to try.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep plugging away. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Hey Mark! I found out some interesting stuff. The model is possibly being bound incorrectly for the 'autocomplete' which is why formController can't validate since it uses models. Can you take another look and possible provide suggestion? Thanks again!

Comment: I think I'd need a plunker or fiddle to help further.  I'm really not following what is going on with inventoryCapabilitiesAutoComplete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: is it possible to invalidate a specific form input field from the controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478355/angularjs-is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-specific-form-input-field-from-the-con)

Comment: @drzaus They both seem to be asking for the same functionality in different contexts. ( Make valid or make invalid ). Considering the answer(s) and view count on this question, marking as duplicate doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I just can't get used to marking questions asked _earlier_ as the duplicate... ;)

Comment: @drzaus I completely agree, but this case is contextual with the amount of information provided on this question.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You cannot directly change a form's validity. If all the descendant inputs are valid, the form is valid, if not, then it is not.

What you should do is to set the validity of the input element. Like so;

```
addItem.capabilities.$setValidity("youAreFat", false);
```

Now the input (and so the form) is invalid. 
You can also see which error causes invalidation.

```
addItem.capabilities.errors.youAreFat == true;
```

Comment: What if ```capabilities``` is a variable? I have an array that contains input names and I want to loop inside the array and set them invalid one by one :/

Comment: What do you mean by variable? It is directly tied to the form itself, not the values in the form. It uses form's `name` attribute and input's `id` attribute. This is different from the values set by `ngModel`

Comment: I found the solution but this was what I meant : ```$scope.addItem['myVariableName'].$setValidity("youAreFat", false);```

Comment: After this it appears that some  input fields are not validates anymore on change or blur

Comment: On angular 1.4.7 and I had to prefix this code with $scope.. `$scope.addItem.capabilities.$setValidity("youAreFat", false);`

Comment: Sorry but you *can* "directly change a form's validity"; see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21111710/34806

Comment: How do I use this when the field is undefined, because the user has not touched the field yet? I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined`.

Answer (score 62):

The answers above didn't help me solve my problem. After a long search I bumped into this [partial solution](http://www.kendar.org/?p=/tutorials/angularjs/part07).

I've finally solved my problem with this code to set the input field manually to ng-invalid (to set to ng-valid set it to 'true'):

```
$scope.myForm.inputName.$setValidity('required', false);
```

Comment: I did the same thing and it works greate. But now i have some problems of revalidating the same field. It does not change to the changed state, which is very anoying. I use ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" to validate on click to a button. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @OliverKK you'll need to invoke `$setValidity` with `true` as the second parameter whenever the input is valid.

Comment: doesn't make sense to be using rootscope, should just be scope

Comment: I tried similar solution, but the problem I found is that if I then try to change the value of the control in the form, it remains invalid. In my case that control is a directive with the inner select. If I set the invalid for my directive (which is ng-form), then I'm unable to remove that invalid status.

Answer (score 19):

I came across this post w/a similar issue.
My fix was to add a hidden field to hold my invalid state for me.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.application.isValid" required="" />
```

In my case I had a nullable bool which a person had to select one of two different buttons. if they answer yes, an entity is added to the collection and the state of the button changes. Until all of the questions get answered, (one of the buttons in each of the pairs has a click) the form is not valid.

```js
vm.hasHighSchool = function (attended) { 
  vm.application.hasHighSchool = attended;
  applicationSvc.addSchool(attended, 1, vm.application);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.application.hasHighSchool" required="" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Did You Attend High School?</label><label class="required" ng-hide="vm.application.hasHighSchool != undefined">*</label></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <button value="Yes" title="Yes" ng-click="vm.hasHighSchool(true)" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': vm.application.hasHighSchool == true}">Yes</button>
    <button value="No" title="No" ng-click="vm.hasHighSchool(false)" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success':  vm.application.hasHighSchool == false}">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - feels hacky but exactly what I was expected :)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. For example :
in you JS controller use this:

```
$scope.inputngmodel.$valid = false;
```

or

```
$scope.inputngmodel.$invalid = true;
```

or

```
$scope.formname.inputngmodel.$valid = false;
```

or

```
$scope.formname.inputngmodel.$invalid = true;
```

All works for me for different requirement. Hit up if this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

to get this working for a date error I had to delete the error first before calling $setValidity for the form to be marked valid.

```
delete currentmodal.form.$error.date;
currentmodal.form.$setValidity('myDate', true);
```