# Set form as invalid in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to set ng-form as invalid in the start, as it is a later part of a wizard. The form contains a grid with elements. Each element has its own validation, but the issue is that when there are no elements the form shows as valid. I need to mark it as invalid for the start case when the number of rows is 0. How can one do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: How do I manually set input to $valid in controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller)

Comment: How can that be duplicate when that question has no answer marked, and one provided states that is not possible to do that? While it clearly is possble to do that and i demonstrate that in the answer. That is why this Q&A is here. So people can find that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some research the following code works fine for me. In the controller:

```
//Set the form as invalid for start.
  $timeout(function(){
   $scope.orderForm.productsForm.$invalid = true;
  });
```

The timeout assures that we gain access to the form. They are not constructed on the first pass through controller so a timeout or watch is needed.
Then we mark form as invalid. A better way could be locating an input that we can mark as invalid using documented api `$setValidity` on ngModelController, but in my use case there is no input yet so we do it in a dirty way.

One caveat is that when one sets this directly like above the corresponding $invalid === ! $valid invariant is broken, so be careful with this hack.

Answer (score 7):

I think the following is a cleaner solution.

```
$scope.$watch('myForm', function (a, b) {
    $scope.myForm.$setValidity('custom', false, window); // 'custom' validation key, binds window as form control
});
```

I like the `$watch` better; Initially, I was going to check "if the form had been created yet", and only then set the validity.

But it seems it's not really needed, the form is created before the $watch is executed its initial time (so no change is called for the watch).

The `$setValidity`seems to be part of the ngForm API (I found it in the [form.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L572) source code), and it's used by form controls themselves which both sets $valid and $invalid.