# Check validity of input on blur (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

By directive, I add a leading zero to an input field on blur, which makes the field valid.  The problem I'm having is that the field still comes back as invalid.

Something like this may work

[AngularJS: How do I manually set input to $valid in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller)

But I would assume the form would have to be checked also.

Any easy way of getting this to work?

**EDIT:**

Here is the directive

```
.directive('leadingZero', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('blur', function() {
                var leadingZero = parseInt(attr["leadingZero"], 10);
                var len = parseInt(elem[0].value.length, 10);

                if(len < leadingZero) {
                    while(parseInt(elem[0].value.length, 10) < leadingZero) {
                        elem[0].value = '0'+elem[0].value;
                    };
                };
            });
        }
    }
})
```

You would use it like this :

```
<input name="month" leading-zero="2" type="text" />
```

Which would change a "5" into "05"

Comment: Can you post your directive and html?

Comment: Without any code, we can't help. Are you applying the scope?

Answer (score 0):

you have to see about pristine and dirty, if your field didn't get any change, $pristine is true and $dirty is false, if it gets change $dirty is true and $pristine is false. Exemple with a code for changing a class `ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.name.$invalid && !form.name.$pristine }"`

Answer (score -1):

Along with your directive that adds leading zeroes, use `input[number]` for easy validation:

```
<input name="month" 
       leading-zero="2"
       type="number"
       min="1" 
       max="12"  
       ng-model="month" />
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kjrv4/)**