# Validation of Form in drop down (<select> tag) in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, html-select, dropdown

I am trying to do a validation on a form which has multiple drop downs available. I have tried using ng-pattern but it seems it works only on input fields.

Now on the ng-change event of select tag I am trying to set the form validation parameter valid manually to false such as $scope...$valid = false but still the valid parameter of form remains true and my condition fails.

Also I am calling the check of valid parameter of form on the button at the end of form.

Please suggest a solution for it.

Comment: Could you please share your code through Fiddle or Plunker? It'd be more helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you. I created this directive to validate equality of two values in form. Directive checks the equality and sets manually validation result to form.

Directive example:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('sameAs', sameAs);

function sameAs() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            sameAs: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    ////////////

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.match = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
            return viewValue === scope.sameAs;
        };
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<form name="testForm">
    <input name="newPassword" type="password"
           ng-model="formData.newPassword">
    <input name="confirmPassword" type="password"
           ng-model="formData.confirmPassword"
           same-as="formData.newPassword">
    <span ng-show="testForm.confirmPassword.$error.match">Passwords is not the same!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.However I have a drop down set and the thing I am trying to achieve is that I do not want to navigate when default option "Select" is selected in the drop down.

Comment: I think this thread probably is the duplicate of what I am trying to achieve.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller