# Manually set a form field as $invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm a newbie to AngularJS, and I'm trying to make a registration form.

What I'm trying to do is check if the username is taken. So basically, I send a request to my PHP file, which then returns `0` or `1` based on the username I post:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/assets/scripts/checkUsername.php",
    data: {
        username: $scope.input_username
    }
}).success(function (data) {
    if (data > 0) {
        $(".userExists").show();
        $scope.loginForm.username.$setValidity("username", true);
    } else {
        $(".userExists").hide();
        $scope.loginForm.username.$setValidity("username", false);
    }
});
```

But for some reason, the submit button still enables like nothing ever happened.

I also tried to do it like this:

```
 $scope.loginForm.username.$invalid = false;
```

but I get no change in result whatsoever.

This is my HTML (I left out the irrelevant fields like password and such.):

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="login()" name="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Gebruikersnaam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required="true" ng-model="input_username" style="  background-image: linear-gradient(#009688, #009688), linear-gradient(#d2d2d2, #d2d2d2);" id="inputDefault" placeholder="Voer jouw gebruikersnaam in." />
        <div class="talkbubble error" ng-show="!loginForm.username.$pristine && loginForm.username.$invalid"> Je moet wel een gebruikersnaam invullen! </div>
        <div class="talkbubble error userExists" style="display: none;"> Deze gebruikersnaam is bezet! </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-default btn-raised" style="background-color:  #009688; color:#fff;">Registreren</button>
</form>
```

How is it that the button doesn't disable when the error is thrown? And how to fix it... Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller

Comment: When do you send this request?

Comment: @dfsq When the username changes

Comment: Your code appears correct - without context, I would guess that you're looking at the wrong scope. If you can reproduce this in a jsbin, that would help. Here's a working model using the necessary bits from your code: http://jsbin.com/seseyu/1/edit?html,js,output