# custom error on ng-repeat on angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can somebody give me some pointer how the best way we can display error per element in the array using ng-repeat

Some snippet/pseucode below

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="validator in validatorArr">
     <input type="text" ng-class="{ 'invalid': validator.name.$valid == false }" ng-model="validator.name" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="save()"/>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myModule").controller("myController",function($scope){
      $scope.validatorArr = [];
      $scope.validatorArr.push({ name : 'test' , expresion : 'test'});

      $scope.save = function(){
             for(obj in $scope.validatorArr){
                    if(obj.name == null){
                        //what is the best way to mark it as invalid
                        obj.name.$valid = false;
                    }
             }
      }   
});
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried [`$setValidity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller)?

Comment: You could repeat over a component or directive where the logic for throwing custom errors would be handled instead of a single controller handling any/all of them.

Comment: If i use setValidity i need to bind it use form?

Comment: i can have one to one lineage between my json object and my form object  . So everytime if my jsom object is invalid  i will set validity of my form name to invalid as well . eg : <span ng-class="{ 'has-error' : 'myForm.field1.$iinvalid }' > . The only problem with this is , once i set this field as invalid in the controller . it doesnt refresh the evaluation in the html side ( two bay data binding ) not happening .