# Custom validation in angularjs compare two dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have two fields `hiring_date` and `expiry_date`
I am using angular UI datepicker.
I want to validate the form if hiring date is **greater than** the expiry date

This is my code:
logic is okay but how can I set this to form error as `false`

```
<small ng-show="formStep1.expiry_date.$invalid && 
formStep1.expiry_date.$touched " class="errorMsg ">
Please enter valid date (YYYY-MM-DD).</small>

<small 
ng-show="formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue < formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue"
class="errorMsg ">
Expiry Date should not be a older than Target Hiring Date.</small>
```

i am getting true and false in this based on two input dates

```
formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue < formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue
```

Is it possible to do validation from view side..?

The message is displaying fine but i want the field `expiry_date` should be like required.

I have tried something like this but not working:

```
<input datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
type="text" 
class="form-control" 
ng-model="expiry_date" 
is-open="config2.opened"  
uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" 
close-text="Close" 
name="expiry_date" 
show-button-bar="false" 
ng-required="formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue < formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue ? 'true': 'false'" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) for any kind of date manipulation. Tom Scott could explain you why [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). Anyway, for your particular case, there is a [moment-angular](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library that could be use as such :

```
/* controller declaration */.('$scope', 'moment', function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.isDateBefore = function(firstDate, secondDate) {
        return moment(firstDate).isBefore(secondeDate);
    }
})


<small 
    ng-show="isDateBefore(formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue, formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue)"
class="errorMsg ">
```

You can learn more about the `isBefore` function [on the official momentjs doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)

Comment: comparison is working fine I want `expiry date` as `$invalid` when comparison `is true`

Comment: Oh, my bad then. let me do some more research

Comment: @Mrworldwide I don't think you need the ternary expression in your `ng-required` condition, just do `ng-required="formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue < formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue"`

Comment: it's not `ternary` problem I need `ng-invalid` or `ng-valid` to validate that form field , not sure how to do it.

Comment: You could look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437435/angularjs-how-do-i-manually-set-input-to-valid-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-if="formStep1.expiry_date.$modelValue < formStep1.hiring_date.$modelValue ? invalidExp(): ''" ></span>


    $scope.invalidExp = function () {
        $scope.formStep1.expiry_date.$valid = false; 
    }
```

this one worked. any better solution then this..?